# WordPress Search result URL looks uncommon

Tags: wordpress, search

something is wrong with my WP search result page URL.
http://localhost/wordpress//?s=Hello
This is what it looks when I search for 'Hello'. What did I do wrong? How to get this to 'http://localhost/wordpress/?s=Hello'. Is my code valid? I injected the WP Walker Menu to add a search box in it and here is the function with the search form.
Here is my code:

```
function add_search_to_wp_menu ( $items, $args ) {
if( 'primary' === $args -> theme_location ) {
$items .= '<li class="menu-item menu-item-search">';
$items .= '<form method="get" class="menu-search-form" action="' . esc_url(home_url( '/' )) . '/"><p><input class="text_input" type="text" value="Search" name="s" id="s" onfocus="if (this.value == \'Search\') {this.value = \'\';}" onblur="if (this.value == \'\') {this.value = \'Search\';}" /></p></form>';
$items .= '</li>';
    }
return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_to_wp_menu', 10, 2);
```

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
esc_url(home_url( '/' ))
```

to

```
esc_url(home_url())
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)